# A server java app frequently forks

Tags: java, linux, fork

I'm an engineer so-so familiar with Unix internals but not with Java :(

I'm administering a server Java app on Linux, and recently found that it forks very frequently (i.e., several times a minute).

My findings are:

1. As the java process occupies >20GB of memory, forking itself occupies another 20GB
2. After fork is done, the child process exits quickly
3. The argv[0] of the child process is '[ls]', which may imply that the parent process invokes /bin/ls

So my question is, is this a preferred behavior of java implementation?

My understanding is that forking a huge process should be a heavy load to the system, and similar things could be done within Java threads with much lighter system loads.

Thanks and regards,
Kick-toss

PS.
I'm sorry I don't have access to the source code of the Java app.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, what you're seeing is the Java program invoking `ls`. Fork+exec is the standard set of system calls you'll see when a program calls out to another command.

Luckily, forking is cheap. Linux doesn't copy all of a program's memory when it creates the child. Instead, it employs copy-on-write to share memory between the two processes. Memory is only actually duplicated when either process changes something.

It would be smarter for the Java program to use Java APIs to get file listings rather than calling out to an external command. Calling `ls` is somewhat lazy. It's nothing you should concern yourself with, though. As an admin, don't worry about it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. You say that the system load won't be affected by the app behavior I mention.
Actually I was working on an analysis of a heavy server load taking place - I may need to look for another culprit.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a preferred behavior of Java implementation?

It isn't the 'behaviour of a Java implementation' at all. It is something mad being done by the Java *application.* Evidently they haven't heard of `File.list()` and its various friends, or better still `java.nio.file.WatchService`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I'm happy to see my guess was not far from the truth. Will ask the app's developer for root cause analysis.